# Unable to Autowire Component with Request Scope in Servlet Filter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

I have a request filter that sits in front of a controller. This filter retrieves a user profile and sets the properties on a `userProfile` Component with Request Scope and then passes on to the next filter.

When trying to access the `userProfile` from inside the filter, the property has not been successfully autowired.

I see the following exception when trying to autowire the `userProfile` from inside the filter:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.userProfile': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.

When trying to access the `userProfile` from inside the controller however, the property has been successfully autowired.

How can I successfully autowire the `userProfile` Component inside the filter?

**Request filter:**

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    public UserProfile userProfile;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {

        ....

        userProfile
            .username(authorizedUser.username())
            .email(authorizedUser.email())
            .firstName(authorizedUser.firstName())
            .lastName(authorizedUser.lastName());
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UsersController {

    @Autowired
    public UserProfile userProfile;

    @GetMapping(
        path = "/current",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public String currentUser() throws ResponseFormatterException {

        System.out.println(userProfile.email());
    }
}
```

**User Profile:**

```
@Component
@RequestScope
public class UserProfile {

    @Getter @Setter
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    @JsonProperty("username")
    private String username;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    @JsonProperty("firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Getter @Setter
    @Accessors(fluent = true)
    @JsonProperty("lastName")
    private String lastName;
}
```

**Security Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurator extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticatingFilter jwtAuthenticatingFilter;

    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(getAuthenticator());
    }

    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
      web
        .ignoring()
           .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
           .antMatchers("/favicon.ico");
    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { 
      http
        .csrf()
          .disable()
        .sessionManagement()
          .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
          .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll()
          .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
          .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
          .addFilterBefore(getFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class)
            .authenticationProvider(getAuthenticator())
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    }

    protected AbstractAuthenticator getAuthenticator() {
        return new JwtAuthenticator();
    }

    protected AuthenticatingFilter getFilter() {
        return jwtAuthenticatingFilter;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me (spring boot 2.1.6.RELEASE), are you sure you don't have any other important parts that could cause the error? Possibly starting a new thread manually somewhere? Or maybe hystrix commands?

Comment: @Shadov I am on `2.1.4.RELEASE`. I'm not messing with threads and have no `hystrix` commands. I am looking around to see if there is something that may be affecting the DI but nothing jumps out.

Comment: @Shadov I have found a security config, I will add it to my question.

Comment: Lot of things that could potentially go wrong, hard to say without seeing everything. Comment out two annotations on SecurityConfig and see if your filter works, it will be clear if this class is at fault. And search your project for `new JwtAuthenticationFilter()` and `@Async`, make sure no one does that.

Comment: @Shadov I know :( but definitely no `new JwtAuthenticationFilter()` anywhere. When I remove those annotations, my Authentication Filter doesn't get hit at all. Don't know if that helps?

Comment: Go to class `RequestContextHolder`, setup a breakpoint and debug it. Focus on `resetRequestAttributes` method, and look for any usages of this class in your code. The only thing that comes to my mind is that some filter before your filter is resetting the request holder, causing your filter to fail.

Comment: is there any reason as to why you are writing a custom jwt filter instead of using the built in one? https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.M3/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2resourceserver-sansboot

Comment: Remove `@Component` from your filter and the `@Autowired`. Create an `@Bean`  annotated method to construct your filter AND create another `@Bean` to register a `FilterRegistrationBean` which you configure so Spring Boot will ignore this filter. Else it will be registered before the spring Security chain and before the setup of the request context needed for scoped beans.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the issue may be that you are attempting to inject a request-scoped bean (smaller scope) into a singleton-scoped bean (larger scope). There are a couple of reasons why this won't work:

- No request scope is active when the singleton is instantiated
- For the second request, the singleton would be working with the same stale bean that was injected for the first request.

You can get around this using a javax.inject.Provider to lazily inject the request-scoped bean on demand.

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    public Provider<UserProfile> userProfileProvider;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {

        ....

        userProfileProvider.get()
            .username(authorizedUser.username())
            .email(authorizedUser.email())
            .firstName(authorizedUser.firstName())
            .lastName(authorizedUser.lastName());
    }
}
```

Spring has a similar interface `org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory` you can use if you are having trouble getting Provider's dependencies set up.

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    public ObjectFactory<UserProfile> userProfileFactory;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain next) throws IOException, ServletException {

        ....

        userProfileFactory.getObject()
            .username(authorizedUser.username())
            .email(authorizedUser.email())
            .firstName(authorizedUser.firstName())
            .lastName(authorizedUser.lastName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, when I try this I get the following error: `NoClassDefFoundError: javax/inject/Provider` even though I have this dependency.

Comment: Edited my response so you can try this without using the Provider interface.

Answer (score 1):

When Spring Boot detects a `Filter` in the `ApplicationContext` it will automatically register it in the chain of filters for the servlet container. However you don't want this to happen in this case as the filter is part of the Spring Security filter chain.

To fix do the following:

1. Remove `@Component` from your filter
2. Don't `@Autowire` the `JwtAuthenticationFilter`
3. Create an `@Bean` method for the `JwtAuthenticationFilter`
4. Create an `@Bean` method for a `FilterRegistrationBean` to disable the registration process.

```
@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
  return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean<JwtAuthenticationFilter> jwtAuthenticationFilterRegistrationBean() {
  FilterRegistrationBean<JwtAuthenticationFilter> frb = new JwtAuthenticationFilter(jwtAuthenticationFilter());
  frb.setEnabled(false);
  return frb;
}
```

Then in your code instead of the `getFilter`  just reference the `jwtAuthenticationFilter()` method.

Comment: How does this work when I have `Autowired` properties inside the `JwtAuthenticationFilter`?

Comment: It is still a bean, just as with `@Component` but now you have a bit more control.

Comment: I don't understand, why do you assume his filter is part of the spring security filter chain?

Comment: I don’t assume... That is because `addFilterBefore` is doing exactly that, adding the filter to the spring security filter chain.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry for the delay in attempting your suggestion. Unfortunately I am still presented with the same error when trying to autowire the `UserProfile`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```java
UserProfile userService = (UserProfile) req.getAttribute("scopedTarget.userProfile");
```

Comment: this probably won't work, as who should have binded the object as a request attribute before?!

Comment: It does work and this was the only way I could solve this issue. userProfile has already been set as RequestScope so its automatically bound.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I believe without custom configuration it is `DispatcherServlet` which binds `RequestContext` to active thread, so when having a filter before that expecting accessing RequestContext won't work (and I believe RequestScope proxies depend on thread-bound RequestContext).

So you must activate `org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener` or `org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter` before your own filter, otherwise RequestScope bean (which is in fact a proxy) should not work.

Answer (score 0):

What about having something like:

```
@Component
public class UserProfile {

    public String getUsername() {
       return getUserDetails().map(UserDetails::getUsername).orElse(null);
    }

    public String getEmail() {
       return getUserDetails().map(UserDetails::getEmail).orElse(null);          
    }

    ...

    private Optional<UserDetails> getUserDetails() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(SecurityContextHolder.getContext())
          .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
          .map(Authentication::getPrincipal);
    }

    private UserDetails getUserDetails(Object principal) {
      // do logic of extracting data... and principal is probably String (username).
    }
 }
```

So your UserProfile won't be request scope anymore, and all you must do is extracting UserDetails object according to principal.
And you can inject the UserProfile anywhere you want, and you won't need the filter anymore.